# Xamarin IOS - Insert a dotted line between 2 UIButtons

Tags: gridview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uibutton, dotted-line

I'm Struggling to insert a dotted line between buttons similar to a GridView with buttons.

Is there anything predefined in the API given by the IOS for Xamarin that solves this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have screenshot or some image reference of what you want?

Comment: I need to insert 2 buttons with a horizontal dotted line separating both... Can you understand with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `UIView` subclass to contain your line drawing so you can apply constraints and align it to the other Views.

In a `UIView` subclass, override the `Draw` method:

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    var path = new UIBezierPath();
    path.MoveTo(new CGPoint(Bounds.Size.Width / 2, 0));
    path.AddLineTo(new CGPoint(Bounds.Size.Width / 2, Bounds.Size.Height));
    path.LineWidth = 6;

    var dashes = new []{ 0 , path.LineWidth * 2 };
    path.SetLineDash(dashes, 0, dashes.Length, 0);
    path.LineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Round;

    (UIColor.White).SetStroke();
    path.Stroke();
}
```

Re: I've been using dotted-line technique for awhile, it is from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26019806/4984832)

In combining this `View` with the answer from this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43877570/4984832), you can create:

[image]